# Generate PDF with PHP and Angular 2

Tags: php, angular, pdf

How would you generate a PDF of an Angular 2 application without having to launch the application? I think that is not possible. Currently, I work with PHP and Angular 2. I think that it is not possible to generate a PDF application without launching it.

So how to do it? Click on a "Generate PDF" button, open a window with the angular 2 application, automatically run a script to generate the PDF and download the PDF and close the window?

I don't know how to do otherwise.

Comment: Can you specifiy what you mean by "generate a PDF application without launching it"? Download a PDF without opening a new browser window?

Comment: I have an application, this application allows to create customer file, when the folder is filled, we can click a button to generate a PDF with the previously completed information. However this PDF must correspond to a template, this template uses angular 2 to display the dynamic data (text, photos, etc.).